# get values from Secret Manager GCP with spring boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

Does anyone have an example of how to get values from the secret manager on GCP in a `.yaml` file (`application.yaml` or `bootstrap.yaml`)? Thanks!

**application.yml:**

```
spring:
 datasource:
  password: ${sm://projects/my-project/secrets/password/versions/1}
```

**bootstrap.yml:**

```
spring:
  cloud:
   gcp:
    secretmanager:
      enabled: true
      secret-name-prefix: 'sm://'
```

Unfortunately I am getting this value: `projects/my-project/secrets/password/versions/1` for password :( What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this dependency:   `implementation("com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager:3.2.1")`
and it worked

Comment: could you explain a little bit or share any reference?

Comment: how to fix the issue in maven project?

Answer (score -1):

You should wrap with double quotes in your first solution and that should do it. Example:

```
spring:
 datasource:
  password: "${sm://projects/my-project/secrets/password/versions/1}"
```

If you want to get the latest version, you can just pass:

```
spring:
 datasource:
  password: "${sm://projects/my-project/secrets/password}"
```

Comment: I tried, but still doesn't work, it's the same error

Comment: Are you using this dependency `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager` ?

Comment: yes i use it:   implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager:1.2.2.RELEASE")

Comment: Strange, I've used the dependency and loaded secrets from yaml file as showed above. Take a look at their docs and check if you are missing anything: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/current/reference/html/secretmanager.html

Comment: can you please help me with which dependencies and versions were you using? I think this is the problem

Comment: I did not pin any version, just passing as: `implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager")`